# Artificial Intelligence propositional symbol

Tags: prolog

1. If the sun shines then it is true that I get wet if it rains.
2. If the sun shines then it is summer.
3. It is not summer.
4. Therefore, I get wet if the sun shines.

I. A proposition symbol represents something that can be either true or false. For example claims 1, 2, and 4. Above, there are statements like “the sun shines” that can be either true or false. Define a propositional symbol for each of these statements.

II. Translate 1, 2, 3 and 4 to propositional logic sentences using your proposition symbols from (i).

Comment: what do you have so far?

Comment: just i need the andwer for this question... if you can please help me

Comment: `(need-answer ^ too-lazy) ⇒ no-help-given` :-)

Comment: i couldn't get answer of my problem, thats y i asked

Answer (score 2):

Using CLP(B) in SICStus Prolog or SWI to to prove the final implication from the preceding statements:

```
?- sat(Sun =< (Wet =< Rain)), 
   sat(Sun =< Summer),
   sat(~Summer),
   taut(Sun =< Wet, T).
```

yielding:

```
...
T = 1,
...
```

This shows that the final implication follows from the previous statements.

Comment: What is the meaning of "If the sun shines then it is true that I get wet if it rains."?, could you please explain ?

Comment: You can look at the truth table of implication and less than equal for the domain {0,1} and see a certain resemblance.